# Debugging Canvas JS

Tags: javascript, debugging, canvas

I have some code here, and I am not sure what's going on.

I am using the touch events to try to track the x and y of the user's finger. If I change `touchmove` to `mousemove`, it will work on a computer. I need it to work on mobile. Please help! Thanks in advance!

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")

canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function(e){
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    p.innerHTML = event.pageX + " " + event.pageY;
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<p id="p">hi</p>
```

Here it is with `mousemove`:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas")

canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(e){
    var x = event.clientX;
    var y = event.clientY;
    p.innerHTML = event.pageX + " " + event.pageY;
});
```

```css
#canvas {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<p id="p">hi</p>
```

Comment: `event.touches[0].clientX`

Comment: @Kaiido Thank you so much it works :D